# how do I load images from AWS S3 into UICollectionView?

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, amazon-s3, uicollectionview

I have a bucket in my AWS S3 backend full of images that I want to load onto my UICollectionViewCell's. What method should I implement to do so? I'm looking for the most efficient method as well.

I may note that currently in my project the frameworks I have are Alamofire, swiftyJSON, and Haneke (for caching purposes) although I do not know how to correctly use them to achieve my goal. I may also add that I'm using Parse.com as my BaaS, so if there is a method that can integrate parse in it, that would be welcomed as well.

So any suggestions **In Swift**?

Comment: @danh check out the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution I suggested is to use Parse.com as the source of metadata for your books and s3 as the storage.  I don't think you need any other components (and I'm particularly suspicious of net-code convenience wrappers for basic iOS stuff).

So I would (and did, to prove it works) setup a parse model like this...
[image: Book as described on parse.com]

And here's a vanilla ViewController in swift that has a collection view and an array of custom swift "Book" objects...

```
// ViewController.swift
import UIKit
import Parse

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak private var collectionView : UICollectionView!
    var books : Array<Book>!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.books = []
    }

    override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        self.loadBooks()
    }

    func loadBooks() {
        var query = PFQuery(className: "Book")
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock { (objects: [AnyObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {
                let bookObjects = objects as! [PFObject]
                for (index, object) in enumerate(bookObjects) {
                    self.books.append(Book(pfBook: object))
                }
            }
            self.collectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
```

Basic stuff.  When the view appears, query parse for book objects, when they are returned, create swift "Book" wrappers around them and reload the collection view.  Here's the swift Book class ...

```
// Book.swift
import Parse

class Book: NSObject {

    var pfBook : PFObject
    var coverImage : UIImage!

    init(pfBook: PFObject) {
        self.pfBook = pfBook
    }

    func fetchCoverImage(completion: (image: UIImage?, error: NSError?) -> Void) {
        let urlString = self.pfBook["coverUrl"] as! String
        let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
        let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url!)
        let queue = dispatch_get_main_queue()

        NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) { (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) in
            if error == nil {
                self.coverImage = UIImage(data: data!)
                completion(image: self.coverImage, error: nil)
            } else {
                completion(image: nil, error: error)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The interesting method fetches the cover image from the url saved in the PFObject.  (Check out the url column in the parse.com data browser.  I took a shortcut here and used an nice dummy image generator on the web.  You would need to implement a method with the same signature, but have it get the image from s3).

The only thing left is the collection view datasource.  Back again in ViewController.swift...

```
// ViewController.swift
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.books.count
}

func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
    let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier("Cell",
        forIndexPath:indexPath) as! UICollectionViewCell
    if cell.backgroundView == nil { // brand new cell
        let v = UIImageView(frame:cell.bounds)
        v.tag = 32
        v.contentMode = .ScaleToFill
        cell.backgroundView = v
    }

    let book = self.books[indexPath.row]
    let coverImage = book.coverImage
    if coverImage == nil {
        book.fetchCoverImage({ (image, error) -> Void in
            collectionView.reloadItemsAtIndexPaths([indexPath])
        })
    } else {
        let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(32) as! UIImageView
        imageView.image = book.coverImage
    }
    return cell
}
```

Notice what we do in the cellForRow... method:  if the book object has a cached coverImage, we place that in the image view.  Otherwise we tell the book to fetch it's cover art and, when finished, reload the cell at the current index path (we don't depend on the cell being current anymore, since time passes while the image is being fetched).

Here's what it looks like running...

[image]

Comment: so i won't have to make a book object for each?

Comment: Each book would have a row in parse.com database, you'd fetch N PFObjects for N books.  You'd build N swift objects, one each wrapping the PFObject fetched.

Comment: I think collectionviewcontroller has a collectionView property, so I think the code is identical `self.collectionView.reloadData()`

Comment: last question, so I already have a custom class for my UICollectionViewCell, and in the controller I have an Outlet to the imageView in the cells. so being I have an already existing imageView, how the `cellForItemAtIndexPath` method change?

Comment: `myCustomCell.myCustomImageView.image = book.coverImage;`

Comment: i mean can you edit the answer to fit a customCell image view

Comment: See where it says `if cell.backgroundView == nil { .... }`?  No need for any of that.  Then see where it says `let imageView = cell.viewWithTag(32) as! UIImageView` ? replace that with `let imageView = cell.myCustomCellImageViewOutlet `

Comment: I'm getting the following error             `*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'attempt to delete item 0 from section 0 which only contains 0 items before the update'`

Comment: the cells don't load and I'm getting that thrown at me in the stack trace

Comment: so i did away with my custom imageView, and just copy and pasted you method, it didn't load up, and i got another error of          `*** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _endItemAnimationsWithInvalidationContext:tentativelyForReordering:], /SourceCache/UIKit/UIKit-3347.44.2/UICollectionView.m:3870`

Comment: Both that and the prior error I've seen associated with collection view editing.  Deleting, reordering, adding with animation, etc.

Comment: WAIT, i just inserted a URL from the dummy image.com site an it loaded perfectly.. whats wrong with my s3 URL

Comment: That image loading method I supplied wasn't built to fetch from s3.  Remember, you were going to build one of those.

Comment: oh ok. what special parameters would i need for it to fetch from s3?

Comment: It would be totally different.

Comment: I'm just reading this http://blog.robkerr.com/tutorial-using-amazon-aws-s3-storage-with-your-ios-swift-app/  It looks like a good tutorial, and the swift code at the end looks like I imagined it would after reading the amazon doc the other day.

Comment: so i just have to revise the load function, not the book class in swift

Comment: I have to shut down for the night.  You'd use the Book class as is, just replace the image loading method with the code from that tutorial.  The author put it in viewDidLoad, but you'd want the method signature to be like the one I suggested.  See where it says `// Set the UIImageView to show the file that was downloaded` in the tutorial.  Instead of doing that, you'd say `self.coverImage = image` and call completion() with the image as mine does.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this problem and have a nice and well working solution, how to load images from AWS S3 to `UIImageView` in cell or other views. To do it I additional use a `SDWebImage` SDK [SDWebImage](https://github.com/SDWebImage/SDWebImage)

So let's create an extension for `UIImageView` and import SDWebImage, then add image cache to caching image links only

```
import UIKit
import SDWebImage

let imageCache = NSCache<NSString, NSString>()

extension UIImageView {

    func loadAsyncWithCacheFromAWSS3(_ link: String?, placeholder: UIImage? = UIImage(named: "placeholder")) {
        guard let unwrappedlink = link else { return self.image = placeholder }
        // Use your own image appearing style
        self.sd_imageTransition = .fade
        if !loadFromCache(unwrappedlink as NSString, placeholder: placeholder) {
            let file = File(bucket: 'YOUR BUCKET', key: unwrappedlink, region: 'YOUR REGION')
            AWSManager.shared.getFileURL(file: file) { [weak self] (string, url, error) in
            guard let validURL = url else { self?.image = placeholder; return }
            imageCache.setObject(NSString(string: validURL.absoluteString), forKey: NSString(string: unwrappedlink))
            guard unwrappedlink == link else {
                guard let key = link else { return }
                self?.loadFromCashe(key as NSString, placeholder: placeholder)
                return
            }
                self?.sd_setImage(with: validURL, placeholderImage: placeholder, options: [.scaleDownLargeImages])
            }
        }
    }
    // quick load from existing cashed link
    @discardableResult
    private func loadFromCache(_ key: NSString, placeholder: UIImage?) -> Bool {
        guard let string = imageCache.object(forKey: key) else { return false }
        let link = URL(string: String(string))
        self.sd_setImage(with: link, placeholderImage: placeholder, options: [.scaleDownLargeImages])
    
        return true
    }

}
```

Here is a singleton class with `getFileURL` method

```
func getFileURL(file: File, completionHandler: @escaping (String?, URL?, Error?) -> Void) {
    let getPreSignedURLRequest = AWSS3GetPreSignedURLRequest()
    getPreSignedURLRequest.bucket = file.bucket
    getPreSignedURLRequest.key = file.key
    getPreSignedURLRequest.httpMethod = .GET
    getPreSignedURLRequest.expires = Date().adjust(hour: 24, minute: 0, second: 0)
    getPreSignedURLRequest.minimumCredentialsExpirationInterval = 10
    
    AWSS3PreSignedURLBuilder.s3PreSignedURLBuilder(forKey: 'YOUR BUILDER URL').getPreSignedURL(getPreSignedURLRequest).continueWith { (task: AWSTask<NSURL>) -> Any? in
        if let error = task.error as NSError? {
            completionHandler(nil, nil, error)
            return nil
        }
        let presignedURL = task.result
        completionHandler(file.key, presignedURL as URL?, nil)
        return nil
    }
}
```

in `Appdelegate` in `func applicationDidReceiveMemoryWarning(_ application: UIApplication)` simple call `imageCache.removeAllObjects()`